# Execute Apache Spark (Scala) code in Bash script

Tags: bash, scala, shell, apache-spark

I am newbie to spark and scala.
I wanted to execute some spark code from inside a bash script. I wrote the following code.

Scala code was written in a separate `.scala` file as follows.

Scala Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println("x="+args(0),"y="+args(1))
  }
}
```

This is the bash script that invokes the Apache-spark/scala code.

Bash Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
Absize=File_size1
AdBsize=File_size2
for i in `seq 2 $ABsize`
do
    for j in `seq 2 $ADsize`
    do
        Abi=`sed -n ""$i"p" < File_Path1`
        Adj=`sed -n ""$j"p" < File_Path2`
        scala SimpleApp.scala $Abi $adj
    done
done
```

But then I get the following errors.

Errors:

```
error:object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
          ^
error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
           ^
error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
           ^
error: not found:type SparkConf
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")              ^
 error: not found:type SparkContext
```

The above code works perfectly if the scala file is written without any spark function (That is a pure scala file), but fails when there are apache-spark imports.

What would be a good way to run and execute this from bash script? Will I have to call spark shell to execute the code?

Comment: Try to provide spark-core dependency in class-path like scala -classpath "*.jar" YourFile.scala

Comment: I used the following command
scala -classpath simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar SimpleApp.scala $Abi $adj 
 but still there is a same error @FaigB

Comment: If you have spark locally use in classpath jar from $spark_home/lib/spark-core_2.10-{version}.jar OR download from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10 and put on classpath

Comment: I have applied the following: 
`scala -classpath /usr/local/spark/jars/spark-core_2.11-2.0.1.jar simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar SimpleApp.scala $Abi $adj`
It gives me following Error:
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream`. 
Sorry to disturb again @FaigB

Comment: Typically, you submit spark jobs with the `spark-submit` command

Comment: you have 2 choices set up spark with environment variable and run as @puhlen told with spark-submit -class SimpleApp simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar $Abi $adj  OR list all required ClassNotFoundException libs in classpath

Comment: Great,now its working fine with 'spark-submit'. You can post it as answer. @FaigB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set up spark with environment variable and run as @puhlen told with `spark-submit -class SimpleApp simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar $Abi $adj`