# importing error when run a Scala script in shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scripting, apache-spark-sql

I created a script of Scala with the following header

```
     #!/bin/sh
     exec scala "$0" "$@"
     !#

     import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
     .....
     .....
```

But there is the following error after running it.

error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

Comment: You may want to look into spark-submit for submitting spark applications: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html also this question might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40606903/execute-apache-spark-scala-code-in-bash-script

Comment: If you want to continue using `spark-shell` in that manner, consider importing spark libs to classpath. Although I highly recommend the approach prince suggested.